# Import Json data and show it in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i started learning angular a week ago, and now im trying to construct a app by myself (because people say that is the best way to learn), im trying to do a thing that i didnt before so dont be so rude to me if it is easy, im trying to build a pokedex, im trying to use data that already exist for it in Json, and import it to the controller on angular so i can use ng-repeat to show the data, but i dont know why it doesnt result, maybe im doing a lot of mistakes but i cant find it :/ , i will post what i did here:

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="pokedex.js"></script>
```

```
<body ng-app ="pokedex">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>All</option>
                <option>Normal</option>
                <option>Watter</option>
                <option>Fire</option>
                <option>Eletric</option>
                <option>Rock</option>
                <option>Ice</option>
                <option>Grass</option>             
                <option>Psychic</option>
                <option>Poison</option>
                <option>Dragon</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row" ng-controller="PokemonController as pokedex">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6" ng-repeat = "pokemon in pokedex.pokemons">
      <p>Name: {{pokemon.Name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('pokedex',[]);

app.controller('pokemonController',['$http',function($http){
     var pokemons = this;
    $http.get('https://pokedex-deluxor.rhcloud.com/getall').success(function(data){
    pokemons = data;
    });
}]);
});
```

Json Url: [Pokedex](https://pokedex-deluxor.rhcloud.com/getall)

Ps: Sorry about my bad english friends :/

Comment: if you mean this ng-controller="PokemonController as pokedex", pokedex is just a alias

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: you should assign the data returned from your http request to the scope object pokedex.

Comment: have you try to [parse the data](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) like `pokemons = JSON.parse(data);` or `$scope.pokemons = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: well i use this way because i saw it in shaping up with angular in codeschool, i tryied to use the .min version and the error is angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Answer (score 0):

you should assign the data returned from your http request to the scope object pokemons.
since you used controller as syntax you should do

> **JS**

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('pokedex',[]);

app.controller('pokemonController',['$http',function($http){
    $http.get('https://pokedex-deluxor.rhcloud.com/getall').success(function(data){
    this.pokemons = data;
    });
}]);
});
```

> **HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="PokemonController as pokedex">
<div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6" ng-repeat = "pokemon in pokedex.pokemons">
  <p>Name: {{pokemon.Name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: inside the http get? can i acces him then in html with no problems?

Comment: you should assign data to pokemons by this.pokemons = data

then you can access it by pokedex.pokemons

Comment: sill dont work :/ angular.js:4640 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module pokedex due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pokedex' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: could you please send your code and i can fix it. tsadikyitbarek@gmail.com

Comment: by the way do you initialise module pokedex more than once may be in other file

Comment: i already send, please explain me what was wrong better then the solution, is learning with mistakes, thank you very much

Comment: no, i just have 1 script and 1 module that is called pokedexApp

Comment: please send it again i couldn`t get it

Comment: tsadikyitbarek@gmail.com

Comment: hey I donot know the problem but i cannot get your email.But i prepare an example that retrieves posts and show their  details.using fake api service called https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts.please tell me your email so i can send it.

Comment: But Error: [$injector:nomod] comes from
1.misspelling modulename
2.not including dependency modules
3.accessing the module before initialising
4.initialising the module more than once

Comment: By the way I have tried the api you used https://pokedex-deluxor.rhcloud.com/getall but itis not allowed to access.

Comment: well i downloaded the pokemon.json and included in my angular app, is there another way i can send to you?

Comment: may be download the latest version and try it.but consider the 4 things i have listed.

Comment: this is my email address tsadikyitbarek@gmail.com

Comment: i already considered, its all fine i already send it again to you

Comment: Sorry My freind I am happy to help but the email is not working.Could you please send it via my facebook account Tsadik Yitbarek.Sorry for the mess.

Comment: please tell me your email address

Comment: filipecosta_10@hotmail.com

Comment: I have sent the example I have done with the latest version of angular.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100008692209756&fref=ts    is this the url? i already send!

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-repeat = "pokemon in pokedex.pokemons"
```

you are using ng-repeat on pokedex.pokemons you have to assign data to pokedex.pokemons from controller where you are getting data.

```
 $http.get('https://pokedex-deluxor.rhcloud.com/getall').success(function(data){
 // assign data here
});
```