# Importing Json Data cant bind it to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm new to AngularJS and still learning. I'm trying to use the RESTful PokeApi to get the JSON data related to a Pokémon. My first step is just to see if I can load a single Pokémon in my application, so I associated the URL directly with the first Pokémon (which is Bulbasaur). I received the data and did a `console.log()` of my list of Pokémon (`this.pokemons` here), but I don't get anything in the view; the data is just empty, and I don't know why! Could someone explain? It looks really confusing to me!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
</head>
<body ng-app ="PokedexApp">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>All</option>
                <option>Normal</option>
                <option>Watter</option>
                <option>Fire</option>
                <option>Eletric</option>
                <option>Rock</option>
                <option>Ice</option>
                <option>Grass</option>             
                <option>Psychic</option>
                <option>Poison</option>
                <option>Dragon</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row" ng-controller="PokemonController as pokedex">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
      <p>Name: {{pokedex.pokemons}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="pokedex.js"></script>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 (function(){

var app = angular.module('PokedexApp',[]);

app.controller('PokemonController',['$http',function($http){
    this.pokemon = {};
    this.ab = "five";
    $http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').then(function(data){
    this.pokemon = data;
     console.log(data);
    });
}]);
```

})();

Comment: The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Json data and show it in angular app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742218/import-json-data-and-show-it-in-angular-app)

Comment: Answer edited, I think it should finally solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the data, no problem to this. The only problem is that you are not storing it.

```
app.controller('PokemonController',['$http',function($http){
    var pokemons = this;
    $http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').success(function(data){
    console.log(this.pokemons);
    });
}]);
```

`this.pokemons` is your controller, basically. You stated that:

`var pokemons = this`

Which basically means, in AngularJS, "my controller will be refered as 'pokemons' through this variable". You are trying to print `this.pokemons`, which represents `this.this` (which does not make sense). To assess that you received the data, try to console.log:

`console.log(data.data)`.

When receiving data from a RESTful API, you will receive the header as well as the data. So printing `data.data` will search the data in your response.

If you want to save this data, you should do:

`var pokemons = {} // Initializing an empty object` and then:

```
$http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').success(function(data){
    pokemons = data.data;
    });
```

And if you want to reference your controller with the `this` keyword, you should do as following:

```
var pokedex = this;
this.pokemons = {};
```

Just below, find the complete sample for your JavaScript:

```
 (function(){

    var app = angular.module('PokedexApp',[]);

    app.controller('PokemonController', ['$http', function($http){
        var pokedex = this;
        this.pokemons = {};
// Calling this object response instead of data makes it more clear, imho        
$http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').success(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    this.pokemons = response.data;
        });
    }]);
    })();
```

Not that you are not obliged to call your controller `pokedex` in your view AND your controller, you can call it whatever you want.

**EDIT**

As stated @biology.info, this request format is deprecated. You should use this format:

```
$http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').then(function successCallBack (response) {
        // Do something if your call is a success
        },
function errorCallBack(response) {
// Do something if your call fails
});
```

**DOUBLE EDIT**

Also, in your view you are calling `pokedex.pokemons` , while in your controller you are calling your variable `pokemon`. Be careful with name consistence. Call either your controller variable `pokemons`, or your HTML variable `pokedex.pokemon`.

Comment: i tryed it, still doesnt work, it always return me to the view an empty object, because it takes a whilte to get the object from the restfull api from pokeApi you know why?

Comment: The `$http` returns what is called a `promise`, which means the operations asked inside the body function will wait for the request to be treated before actually doing it.
As your variable calling. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi Yassie Badache, the problems was not exactly with that what you mean, the problem was that i was using this, i saw shaped up with angular on codeschool and really liked the way he used 'this' on angular but as i can see now it doesnt work very well, with $scope i got the name of the bulbasur, problem solved thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome, just don't forget that the `this` usage is still possible if you want to pass oyur controller as a reference, you just need to understand how it works (I'm actually using it, don't have a single `$scope` :p). Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your controller body:

```
var pokemons = this;
$http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').success(function(data){
  console.log(this.pokemons);
});
```

First, I'm not sure what `var pokemons = this` is intended to do, but what that is actually doing is setting `pokemons` to the controller itself. `this` within the controller refers to the controller.

If what you meant to do, as indicated in your `get` response function, was to declare a `pokemons` property on your controller instance so that you can reference `this.pokemons` later, what you'd want to do is:

```
this.pokemons = {};
```

That will set `this.pokemons` to an empty object to begin with.

As for the `$http` call you make, as @Sajeetharan mentioned, you need to actually set the value of `this.pokemons` to `data`; it won't magically happen in the background. In addition, as @biology.info said, it's better form these days to use `$http.get(...).then()` instead of `$http.get(...).success()`. All together, that will produce this code:

```
$http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').then(function(data){
  this.pokemons = data;
  console.log(this.pokemons);
});
```

#### Edit

I forgot above to keep track of my `this` contexts. Annoyingly, the `this` inside the `.then()` refers to the callback function, not the controller, so you won't actually attach `pokemon` to the controller. To fix this, store `this` in a variable at the top of the controller:

```
var pokedex = this;
$http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/').then(function(response){
  pokedex.pokemons = response.data;
  console.log(pokedex.pokemons);
});
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/40oswjyb/2/

Comment: i tryed it, still doesnt work, it always return me to the view an empty object, because it takes a whilte to get the object from the restfull api from pokeApi you know why?

Comment: Well, what the `.then()` method does is it hangs on to the callback function you give it, waits until it gets a response back from the AJAX call, and then calls the function and passes the response data in as the first argument, so taking a long time shouldn't be a problem. Did you make sure to put the `console.log(this.pokemons)` *inside* the `.then()` callback function? If so, could you edit your question and post the code you've tried in response to our answers at the bottom? I suspect there might be another little error in there somewhere

Comment: just a question before i do it, that .then comes with which version of angular?

Comment: i edited the question, now i receive a simple object with then like this Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: Right, so the actual data you want should be in `data.data`. As for angular versions, I'm not positive which version first included `.then()`, but it's definitely been around for several major versions; if I had to guess I'd say it first appeared in Angular v1.3.x

Comment: well, i got the object in the console.log, but it still didnt pass to the view on the html cant figure out why

Comment: See my edit; forgot about the different `this` contexts. Also, I noticed that your JavaScript uses `pokemon` but your HTML uses `pokemons`; remember to make sure your variable names are consistent! Easy mistake to make

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in previous answers, you are not actually storing the data you fetch. One way to achieve what you are trying to do:

Controller:

```
app.controller('PokemonController', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {   
    $http
    .get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/')
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.pokemons = data;
    });
}]);
```

DOM:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="PokemonController as pokedex">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6">
        <p>Name: {{pokemons}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Because we are storing `pokemons` in the controller's `$scope`, we don't need to use the `pokedex.pokemons` notation anymore.

Comment: i tryed it, still doesnt work, it always return me to the view an empty object, because it takes a whilte to get the object from the restfull api from pokeApi you know why?